# Proving the binomial series for all real (complex) n using Taylor series

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

We know the binomial theorem
$$(a+b)^n =\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^k$$
can be proved using mathematical induction $\forall n\in N$. What I've been trying is to prove it for all real $n$ (or even complex $n$) as follows:
Consider the function $$f(b)=(a+b)^n$$ then the $k$-th derivative is given by:
$$f^{(k)}(b)=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)(a+b)^{n-k}$$ Considering now the taylor series of the function $f$ at $0$ one gets:
$$f(b)=(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(b-0)^k $$
but $f^{(k)}(0)=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)a^{n-k}$ and complementing this with $\frac{1}{k!}$ gets  the binomial coefficient $n\choose k$ therefore
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^k$$ Which would be valid since for $n\in N$ the terms with $k>n$ are equal to zero so this would terminate at $n$ (and is the original binomial theorem). For $n\notin N$ this would turn into infinite series. Is this a good approach and would this also prove that the binomial theorem holds for all $n\in C$?

Comment: but Taylor series only represent the function when the remainder, on Taylor formula, goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.Thus you need to prove this to finish completely.

Comment: more clearly: you need to show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}ka^{n-k}b^k$ converges. Hint: observe when the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}k(b/a)^k$ converges.

Comment: evaluated the $lim_{k\to\infty}|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|=\frac{b}{a}(1+{{n-1}\choose {k-1}})$. The binomial coefficient for k infinite tends to zero therefore my formula is valid when $b/a<1$, Would that be correct?

Comment: Im not sure that we can conclude that if $\binom{n}k\to 0$ then the series converges for $|b/a|<1$. However you can conclude this using the ratio test. With a bit of work it can be shown also that it converges when $|b/a|=1$.

Comment: Well, what i showed is that the limit of the ratio as $k\to\infty$ is just $b/a$ so to for it to be convergent, this ratio must be $b/a<1$. Or am i wrong?

Comment: yes, you are right. Before to edit your previous comment it wasnt completely clear what you did. But the inequality $b/a<1$ is only true when $a,b>-1$, this is the reason that in general we write $|b/a|<1$

Comment: Okay, but then, because the formula is symetric because $(a+b)^n=(b+a)^n$ and either $|b/a|<1$ or $|a/b|<1$ so i can conclude that it convegerges for any $a,b,n \in R$

Comment: No. If $n\notin \Bbb N$ then the binomial series only converges when $|b|\le|a|$. If $|b|>|a|$ the series diverges. Also there are other special cases, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence).